# ERROR while creating new liferay portal instance

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, portal

I already have few portal instance set up in liferay portal. When I go to Server-> portal instances ->Add

After filling all the fields and clicking on save, it shows error and nothing is created.

I only see **ERROR [ajp-bio-9409-exec-8][SiteIndexer:160] No Group exists with the key {companyId=XX, classNameId=XX, classPK=XX}** exception in logs which is not very helpful.

Please help me in fixing this error

Comment: What version of Liferay are you using?

Comment: liferay 6.1 version

Comment: 6.1 what?  Minor version differences mean a lot.  An earlier version means the recommendation is to update, but a later version (w/o updates available) points to something else.